# REST. Checking the type of incoming field

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing, cucumber

how can I check the field type of the incoming response to the REST request.

For example, I receive an answer with the
"pay" field:"1000"
I want to check that the incoming field, its value is of type int
What verification methods are there?

Comment: If it's Spring, you dont have to do anything. Spring itself tries to convert the type as per what you've defined. If it fails, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: No, I'm just an example. The bottom line is that there is a situation where I need to do a check to make sure that all the fields received have the right type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Rest Assured](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/5.1.1)

Say you have this endpoint: https://mocki.io/v1/0f2701f8-46ab-48b5-9584-7e58da29498d

that returns:

```
{
  "pay": 1000
}
```

Then your code could be:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
    System.out.println(RestAssured
            .get(new URI("https://mocki.io/v1/0f2701f8-46ab-48b5-9584-7e58da29498d"))
            .jsonPath()
            .get("pay") instanceof Integer);
}
```